# receiving Acces Denied when get status of UWF_Filter using WMI in c#

Tags: c#, wmi, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to get de status of the UWF Wilter in Windows 10 IoT as an User. I'm using the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionOptions Options = PrepareOptions();

            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope();
            scope.Path = new ManagementPath(@"\\localhost\root\StandardCimv2\embedded");
            scope.Options = Options;
            scope.Connect();

            using (ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(scope.Path.Path, "UWF_Filter", null))
            {
                //next line failes with Access Denied under normal user account
                ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
                foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
                {
                    string UWFstate = (bool)mo.GetPropertyValue("CurrentEnabled");
                    if ( UWFstate )
                    {
                        // Do Something When Enabled
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Do Something Else When Disabled
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            trow;
        }
    }       


public static ConnectionOptions PrepareOptions()
    {
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default;
        options.EnablePrivileges = true;
        return options;
    }
```

When I try to run this code under a normal user account and with the write filter enabled the getinstances() method returns Access Denied. With the write filter disabled code runs fine. Also when run under an administrative user it works flawless.

When I try this using PowerShell I also receive an Access Denied message.

Documentation at MSDN of the UWF_Filter class states:

> You must use an administrator account to make any **changes** to the configuration settings for UWF. Users with any kind of account can **read** the current configuration settings.

So I presume that a normal user must be able to read the UWF configuration. Or do I make a mistake somewhere?

Any idea?

Thanks Michel.

Comment: What's your [Windows Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwf-filter#requirements)?

Comment: Windows10 IoT Enterpise LTSB 2016 build 1607 (OS build 14393.726)

Comment: I can confirm your described behaviour. Tested it on Win10 IOT Enterprise 2016 LTSB build 14393.1770

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After so much of research finally found that WMI does not provide access even for admins to write exclusions  in UWF_Volume (tried via PowerShell ,C# , C++ from admin account) while UWF_Filter.Enable() , UWF_Filter.Disable() and few other methods worked properly.
   So, therefore to add exclusion, I used command tool from my program.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know if UWF Filter is on, you can use a workaround:

```
unit osWMIUtils;

interface

type
  TWMI_UWF_Filter = record
  const
    RC_EMPTY            = 0;
    RC_HAS_DATA         = 1;
    RC_ACCESS_DENIED    = 2;
    RC_INVALID_CLASS    = 3;
    RC_GENERIC_ERROR    = 4;
  public
    ResultCode: Integer;
    CurrentEnabled: Boolean;
    NextEnabled: Boolean;
    procedure Init;
  end;

function GetUWFFilterInfo: TWMI_UWF_Filter;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Win.ComObj,
  Winapi.Wbem,
  Winapi.ActiveX;

{ TWMI_UWF_Filter }

procedure TWMI_UWF_Filter.Init;
begin
  ResultCode := RC_EMPTY;
  CurrentEnabled := False;
  NextEnabled := False;
end;

{ generic functions }

{**
 *  TAKE CARE
 *  =========
 *  Unified Write Filter (UWF) info are available ONLY if installed and in following Windows versions:
 *    Windows xx Enterprise
 *    Windows xx Education
 *    Windows xx IoT Core Enterprise
 *
 *  so if you take a query of 'UWF_Filter' on an unsupported Windows version a WBEM_E_INVALID_CLASS will be raised.
 *
 *  If Unified Write Filter (UWF) is available but not active (CurrentEnabled = False) the query returns the actual
 *  values of CurrentEnabled/NextEnabled with following code executed at any priviledges level.
 *
 *  If Unified Write Filter (UWF) is available and active (CurrentEnabled = True) the query returns the actual
 *  values of CurrentEnabled/NextEnabled only with code executed with Administrator prividedges otherwise raises a
 *  WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED exception.
 *
 *  TWMI_UWF_Filter.ResultCode:
 *    RC_EMPTY            = There are not evaluated data yet.
 *    RC_HAS_DATA         = UWF Filter available and data aligned with UWF Filter settings.
 *    RC_ACCESS_DENIED    = UWF Filter available and active. NextEnabled info is not accessible.
 *    RC_INVALID_CLASS    = UWF Filter not available. CurrentEnabled/NextEnabled to False by default.
 *    RC_GENERIC_ERROR    = UWF Filter cannot be detected for an error. CurrentEnabled/NextEnabled to False by default.
 *
 **}
function GetUWFFilterInfo: TWMI_UWF_Filter;
const
  WbemUser            = '';
  WbemPassword        = '';
  WbemComputer        = 'localhost';
  WbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  IValue: LongWord;
  OEnum: IEnumvariant;
  FWMIService: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject: OLEVariant;
  NeedUninitialize: Boolean;
  FSWbemLocator: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
begin;
  Result.Init;
  try
    NeedUninitialize := CoInitialize(nil) = S_OK;
    try
      FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
      FWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\StandardCimv2\embedded', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
      FWbemObjectSet := FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM UWF_Filter','WQL', wbemFlagForwardOnly);
      OEnum := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
      while OEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, IValue) = 0 do
      begin
        Result.CurrentEnabled := FWbemObject.CurrentEnabled;
        Result.NextEnabled := FWbemObject.NextEnabled;
        Result.ResultCode := TWMI_UWF_Filter.RC_HAS_DATA;
      end;
      FWbemObject := Unassigned;
    finally
      if NeedUninitialize then
        CoUninitialize;
    end;
  except
    on E: EOleException do
    begin
      Result.Init;
      case E.ErrorCode of
        WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED:
        begin
          Result.ResultCode := TWMI_UWF_Filter.RC_ACCESS_DENIED;
          Result.CurrentEnabled := True;
          Result.NextEnabled := False;
        end;
        WBEM_E_INVALID_CLASS:
        begin
          Result.ResultCode := TWMI_UWF_Filter.RC_INVALID_CLASS;
          Result.CurrentEnabled := False;
          Result.NextEnabled := False;
        end;
        else
        begin
          Result.ResultCode := TWMI_UWF_Filter.RC_GENERIC_ERROR;
          Result.CurrentEnabled := False;
          Result.NextEnabled := False;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Result.ResultCode := TWMI_UWF_Filter.RC_GENERIC_ERROR;
      Result.CurrentEnabled := False;
      Result.NextEnabled := False;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```